# Как повысить приоритет стилей в css, если к странице подключены два файла css

Tags: css

В index.css задан цвет кнопки

```
button {
    border-color: #659BDB;
    color: #191970;
}
button:hover {
    background: #659BDB;
    color: white;
}
```

Затем на другой странице в element.css он переопределен

```
.payment {
    border-color: #EE0000;
    color: #EE0000;
}
.payment::hover {
    background: #EE0000;
    color: white;
}
```

Цвет рамки поменялся на нужный. Но при наведении мышки, кнопка подсвечивается синим. Что не так?

Comment: Можно использовать important.

Comment: Хотя советую отделить изменяемыме свойства основного класса на отдельный, к примеру, default

Comment: `hover` - это псевдо-класс, а не псевдо элемент. Его нужно использовать только с одним `:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В css различают [псевдо-классы и псевдо-элементы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Pseudo-classes_and_pseudo-elements).

Для указания псевдо-класса используется одинарное двоеточие (`:`), например:

- [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)
- [:focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

Для указания псевдо-элементов используется двойное двоеточие (`::`), например:

- [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)
- [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

---

Для обратной совместимости оставили возможность указывать псевдо-элементы с одним двоеточием.

Так как в вопросе речь про псевдо-класс, нужно изменить

```
.payment::hover
```

на

```
.payment:hover
```

```css
button {
    border-color: #659BDB;
    color: #191970;
}
button:hover {
    background: #659BDB;
    color: white;
}

.payment {
    border-color: #EE0000;
    color: #EE0000;
}

.payment:hover {
    background: #EE0000;
    color: white;
}

.payment::hover { /* не работает */
    background: black;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="payment">button</button>
```